# Why I found this error during opening sublime text

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

When I start my sublime text3, I found the following command. What is the problem? How I can solve it? I use Ubuntu 16.

> Error trying to parse file: Unexpected character, expected a comma or closing bracket in Packages/User/Default (Linux).sublime-keymap:2:9

[image]

Comment: It means something is wrong in the file Default (Linux).sublime-keymap. You need to show us the contents of that to tell exactly what is wrong, but most likely you tried to edit it and missed a bracket or comma so now it's invalid JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess what! I had the same error when I started using sublime text!

open this file: `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/Default (Linux).sublime-keymaps` with whatever program, but not sublime, and replace all the content with `[]`

Then, restart sublime text, and it should work.

Matt

Comment: this is hardly the solution since you delete every keybinding with that

Comment: I agree, it's not the best solution, although it sounds like he didn't have any shortcuts, and he wasn't able to restart ST. So, that the best *quick* solution.